# ¿Cómo volver a mis archivos que se han remplazado por usar el comando 'git pull origin master'?

Tags: git, github, control-de-versiones

Soy un nuevo en lo que es laravel git todo esto, he querido bajar lo último que han hecho los ingenieros y mi trabajo que ya estaba terminado se borró o se reemplazó por lo que estaba en el servidor remoto, y he perdido todo, quisiera saber la solución para tener mis archivos de nuevo y poder hacer el procedimiento como es, y no terminar reemplazando mi trabajo por lo que otros hacen o suben en el servidor. Gracias de ante mano, me salvarían la vida.

Comment: Habias hecho "commit" de tu trabajo en tu rama o en algun sitio?

Comment: no eso fue lo que me falto

Comment: Si no has guardado ninguno de tus cambios en un `commit` o un `stash` creo que poco puedes hacer... No se si en el entorno donde trabajas tienes alguna  pestaña de cambios recientes o algo donde puedas ver tus cambios pasados :(

Comment: Me temo que sí tus cambios nunca han sido subidos a una rama o a master en el servidor poco puedes hacer a menos que tú ya tuvieras una versión de backup en tu local y en otra raíz. Por si acaso te comparto a continuación una de las guías que a mí más me ayuda en el uso de 'git', por si en adelante te puede resultar de ayuda:

https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.es.html

Comment: entonces creo que la cague, si no hay remedio perdí un mes de trabajo, por no documentarme bien, trabajo con JetBrains PhpStorm

Comment: Siempre debes hacer "commit" constantemente de tu trabajo, porque eso es tu respaldo local y muestra de tu progreso, cada función terminada y probada se debe subir localmente y antes de un pull debes realizar un fetch para ver si hay cambios, ademas ¿Cuál comando ejecutaste? porque el pull no sobre escribe código que tenga cambios sin subir.

Comment: Si solo hiciste git pull origin, se deben haber agregado los cambios del branch remoto a los tuyos. Si hubiera algún cambio incompatible con los tuyos te tiene que haber salido un mensaje diciendo que hay "Conflicts" a resolver. En ambos casos tus cambios siguen estando. Usa `git status` para ver los archivos que están modificados en tu working copy y  `git diff origin/master` para comparar tu working copy con el master remoto. (Si tuviste conflicts y seleccionaste que tome los cambios del remoto como buenos es otro tema)

Answer (score 1):

En tus comentarios dices que trabajas con PhpStorm. Los IDE de JetBrains guardan durante días el histórico de cada fichero para contrarrestar la funcionalidad de "autograbado" cada 5 segundos que tiene ese IDE (a veces puede ser un quebradero de cabeza, cuando haces cambios a un fichero sólo para mostrar a alguien un ejemplo de código que no quieres realmente guardar).

De todos modos me extrañaría que hubieses perdido tus cambios con un `git pull`: Si tienes cambios hechos que no se han "commiteado", git no te permite hacer un pull si esos ficheros entran en conflicto con los commits con los que estás haciendo el *merge*.

Mira bien si has hecho un stash: comprueba con `git stash list` si tienes cambios guardados o si directamente tus cambios siguen ahí